# Get Process ID for a launched application using NSWorkspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, command-line

I am having difficulty getting the pid of a launched file in an application. I think I'm nearly there but I keep getting a null:

```
[sharedWorkspace openFile:@"/Users/abs/Documents/my.txt" withApplication:@"TextEdit"]; 

 NSDictionary * currentAppInfo = [sharedWorkspace activeApplication];

 int pid = [[currentAppInfo objectForKey: @"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"] intValue];

 NSLog(@"%@", pid); // (null), using @i, @u, @d I get 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is for a commnand line application being built in xcode 4.2.

Comment: Changing `NSLog(@"%@", pid)` into `NSLog(@"%i", pid)` does work for me. It gives the Process ID of the current running application though, not the one used to open the file with.

Comment: @Jef Ah, I need the process id of the application I just launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing your app as a command line application, you are likely not even using AppKit.  Is the AppKit.framework linked in your project?

Does the `[NSWorkspace openFile: withApplication:]` call even work?

Check out this [CocoaBuilder thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/215467-use-of-appkit-in-command-line-app-on-headless-node.html).  One quote that stands out to me is:

> AppKit in general requires a window server connection.

To get the process id (pid) of the TextEdit you launched, I believe you're going to have to try something else.

Of course you realize that `[NSWorkspace activeApplication]` has been deprecated as of 10.7, yes?

Comment: I am using '#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>' and '#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>'. Is it possible for 'NSWorkspace' to be used in a command line application? What other options are there to allow me to open an open and gets its window process id?

Comment: Swicthed to a Cocoa application and it works. Its annoying to have a blank window appear but it does the job. I think you're right about te window server connection for this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included the Cocoa/AppKit framework;
You can get the process ID of an app by filtering [NSWorkspace's runningApplications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/runningApplications) for TextEdit and then get its [processIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSRunningApplication/processIdentifier) property.

```
NSLog(@"%i", [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.TextEdit"] processIdentifier]);
```

(I'm not behind my Mac right now so this is untested)

Comment: I tested this as well and it doesn't work in a command line application. Works in Cocoa though.